# How to multi-sort elements in a List

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I sort a list of 3 variables?

[image: screencapture]

The list has three values: clusCode, DocCode, and xValue.

```
List<item> unSORT=new list<item>();

var okSORT=from element in unSORT
           orderby element.xValue descending
           select element;
```

Comment: This question is very unclear indeed. There's no reason for the image link (it's just text really), but you should have included all the relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:-

```
var okSort = unSort.OrderByDescending(x=> x.xValue)
               .ThenBy(x=> x.clusCode)
               .ThenBy(x=> x.DocCode)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Well that creates a new list - but it only uses one of the fields, and will use that field in the wrong sense (the OP wants the highest xValue first).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is *very* unclear, but I suspect you want something like:

```
var okSORT = from element in unSORT
             orderby element.xValue descending, element.clusCode, element.DocCode
             select element;
```

That's assuming you want it sorted primarily by `xValue` (largest first), then by `clusCode` (lexicographically earliest first), then by `DocCode` (lexicographically earliest first). That will return an `IEnumerable<item>`. If you need a `List<item>`, you can just use the `ToList()` method:

```
// orderby clause broken into multiple lines to avoid horizontal scrolling - 
// that makes no difference
var okSORT = (from element in unSORT
              orderby element.xValue descending,
                      element.clusCode,
                      element.DocCode
              select element).ToList();
```

At that point it may make sense to use the extension methods directly:

```
var okSort = unSort.OrderByDescending(element => element.xValue)
                   .ThenBy(element => element.clusCode)
                   .ThenBy(element => element.DocCode)
                   .ToList();
```

Note that this does *not* sort the existing list in place. If you need to do that, you should create a `Comparer<item>` and use `List<T>.Sort`.

I would *strongly* suggest that you work on your naming, too. The type name, property names and variable names are all unconventional/unclear.

Comment: @RahulTripathi: What do you mean by "is that not fine"? Both our answers use LINQ, but yours only orders by a single field (in the wrong order).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ThenBy` or the `ThenByDescending` clause

```
from element in unSort
orderby element.xvalue descending,
element.clusCode,
element.Doccode 
select element
```

using the lambda syntax

```
unSort.OrderByDescending(x=>x.xvalue).ThenBy(x=>x.clusCode).ThenBy(x=>x.DocCode)
```

Comment: That's not how you express multiple orderings in a query expression.

Comment: @Jon....I combined the lambda syntax with the query expression. Thanks for pointing it out.